# Creating links between arrays of pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

how can I create links between two arrays of pointers in C++.
I (obviously) tried the method where I declared 2 pointer Arrays and started equating their indexes individually but C++ would give me an error (stating: cannot convert int* to int**). 
So...any solutions? 
For a better understanding of the question, look at this link:
[QUESTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfVsQ.jpg)

EDIT: 
Here's a simple breakdown code that I tried (but it didn't work at all):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 int main ()
{
    int *A[4];
    int *B[4];
A[0] = &B[1];
}
```

Comment: If the two arrays are declared as int* then you are just doing the assignment wrong.  So we need to see the code.

Comment: Explain what exactly you mean by "links between two arrays of pointers". This is mostly a meaningless statement in C++. C++, the language, deals strictly with types and objects. Both arrays here, `A` and `B` contain pointers to `int`s. That's their type. `A[0]` is a pointer to an `int`. `&B[1]` is a pointer to element #1 of B, or a pointer to a pointer to an int. That's why you get the compilation error. It is unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah 
I edited the post by including my code. In addition to that. I also took a few other approaches, such as: Making one pointer array as a "Pointer to pointer array" and the other Array as a simple pointer array. And while that worked in storing the address of latter array in the former array, it didn't work the other way around. I hope I'm making sense though.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik
To put it briefly, I am trying to (as the assignment states in the picture) create two arrays. Both of them storing the addresses  of various indexes of each other. For example: A[0] should have address of B[1] as it's value. And in the same way B[1] should have the address of A[0] as it's value.  Again, I hope I am making sense.  But once again, you can take a look at the picture that I've attached for a better understanding.

Comment: `void* A[4]; void* B[4]; A[0] = &B[1]; B[1] = &A[0];`

Comment: Hey there @Eljay  
Thanks a lot for the answer. This really helped me. Can't believe it was really this simple.

Comment: @TheHassaanAtif Please don't assume that everyone will -- or even can -- follow your link and view your image. Questions on this site must be self-contained, requiring no external resources to be understood. (External resources can be used as supplements, though.) Describing your task in your own words would improve the quality of this question.

Comment: @JaMiT 
My apologies for not making the question clear on this post here. I am still relatively new here. Either way, I'll keep that in mind for future references. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the picture in your description, it seems that only elements of `A` need to point to elements of `B`. This means `B` can just be a regular array of `int`s:

```
int *A[4];
int  B[4];
A[0] = &B[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think that B can be a regular array here. I guess that ambiguity arises from the one directional arrows, but then again, the values stored in the "B" array are arbitrary memory addresses (which I typically assumed belonged to the first array). 
Either way, my question has been answered in the comments above.